# When to draw to avoid drawing the defective ball out of $n+1$ balls?

Tags: probability

Can someone confirm my intuition for part $b$ of the following problem? There is a solution online that states the answer should be completely analogous to part $a$, so I may have the wrong intuition here.

### Problem

Suppose we have $n+1$ balls, where $1$ of them is defective. $n+1$ people walk up to the urn and draw a ball randomly. The person that draws the defective ball loses.

a) Should we draw first, last, or somewhere in the middle to not lose if every ball is equally likely to be drawn?

#### Answer

All $(n+1)!$ permutations of the balls are equally likely. The defective ball is equally likely to be any of the $n+1$ balls, so the probability that we draw it is $\frac{1}{n+1}$ irrespective of when we choose to draw.

b) Suppose the probability of drawing a ball is proportional to it's weight. All non defective balls have weight $w$. The defective ball has weight $v$. Thus, the probability of drawing a particular ball is it's weight divided by the sum of the weights of the remaining balls.
Should we draw first, last, or somewhere in the middle now?

#### Answer

Consider the extreme case of the defective ball being super massive $(v \approx 1)$. Then, it is more likely that a person draws the defective ball rather than a non defective ball, so we want to draw last. On the other hand, if $v$ is much smaller than $w$, then, at any stage of the experiment, drawing the defective ball is less likely than not, but after each draw of a non defective ball, the probability of drawing the defective one increases since there are less balls left in the urn. Thus, we want to be one of the first ones to draw.

So the answer depends on the relationship of $w$ and $v$.

Comment: Unless there's something omitted in the description, you are correct.  Suppose $n=10,w=10,v=1$.  The probability that the first person draws the ball is $\frac12$.

Comment: @saulspatz I may be blanking out here, but how did you get $\frac{1}{2}$? $10$ balls have weight $10$ and $1$ ball (the defective one) has weight $1$. So, the probability that the first person draws the defective ball is $\frac{v}{10w + v} = \frac{1}{101}$.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.  The values of $v$ and $w$ are reversed.

Comment: You are correct. It's most obvious in the case where there are exactly two balls. What does the other solution you saw say?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It says, analogous to part a, the probability of us drawing the defective ball is $\frac{v}{v + nw}$ irrespective to when we draw. This is in contrast to the intuition I describe in my solution.

Comment: Yep, that's just not true, and again the case of two balls is already enough to see that it's not true. The change in weight breaks the symmetry being used in the first case. Online solutions are not trustworthy!